# How to write a Java program to include whitespaces at the beginning of a string that we want to reverse?

Tags: java, string, whitespace, reverse

I want to reverse a string.
input:    Computer;
This input contains 4 whitespaces in the beginning of the word 'computer'.I want to include these 4 whitespaces in the beginning of the reversed string also.So,the program should include all the whitespaces I put at the beginning while taking the reverse too(I put 4 whitespaces as an example only).
output:"    retupmoc";
I am attaching my code here.

```
package BasicTesting;
import java.util.*;

    public class Corrected_StringRev {
    
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in); //System.in is a standard input stream  
            System.out.print("Enter a string: ");  
            String str= sc.nextLine();        
            String reversed = reverseString( str );
            
            System.out.println( reversed );
        }
        
        public static String reverseString( String newString ) {
            
            char ch[]=newString.toCharArray();  
            String rev="";  
            for(int i=ch.length-1;i>=0;i--){  
                rev+=ch[i];  
            }  
            return rev;  
       
        }
    }
```

How can I change this code to include the above requirement.Please,rewrite the code.Hope ypu will help.Thanks in adavance!

Comment: An easy solution should be like this: when you iterate over the string, you count the number of trailing whitespaces. When you find the first non-whitespace character, you reverse the remaining string and finally concatenate the whitespaces with the reversed string.

Comment: Thsnk you all for your effort in helping me!

Answer (score 0):

The logic is simple:

1. Traverse the start of the string and add whitespaces to `rev` until you meet the first non-whitespace
2. Do your string reversal and stop before the whitespace section begins

```
public static String reverseString(String newString) {
    char ch[] = newString.toCharArray();  
    String rev = "";
    int nWhitespace;
    for (nWhitespace = 0; nWhitespace < ch.length; nWhitespace++) {
        if (!Character.isWhitespace(ch[i]) {
            break;
        }
        rev += ch[i];
    }

    for(int i = ch.length - 1; i >= nWhitespace; i--){  
        rev += ch[i];  
    }
    return rev;  
}
```

By the way, you can improve your code by using `StringBuilder` instead of `+=`.

Answer (score 0):

Here instead of keeping a count and then adding it, we will be checking if the character we are at currently in the string is a whitespace character. If yes, we add a space to our string builder.

As soon as we come across a non-whitespace character, we *break* out of the loop.

```
strB.append(new StringBuilder(inputString.trim()).reverse().toString());
        return strB.toString();
```

What this code does is:

- Take string inputString and trim it (remove trailing and leading whitespaces.
- Creates a new (anonymous) object of a StringBuilder and reverses it.
  Convert it into a string to append it to our original StringBuilder strB after the whitespaces.
  Finally, we convert it into String and return it.

Some tips:

- I will be using StringBuilder as it is mutable so saves space and also it contains a function to reverse it directly.
- You should not call the length function of string in the loop as it will call it for every loop. Better to store the value in a variable and use that variable in the loop.

```
public static String reverseString(String inputString) {
    StringBuilder strB = new StringBuilder();
    int len = inputString.length();
    for (int i = 0; i<len && inputString.charAt(i) == ' '; i++) {
        strB.append(" ");
    }
    strB.append(new StringBuilder(inputString.trim()).reverse().toString());
    return strB.toString();
}
```

Comment: Don’t make the entire loop body an `if` statement with `break`. That’s effectively establishing another loop condition, so you can write it as loop condition in the first place: `for(int i = 0; i < len && inputString.charAt(i) == ' '; i++) { strB.append(' '); }`

Comment: @Holger But this loop will apeend whitespace to our strB for the trailing whitespaces also. Which is not what we want. We only want to copy the beginning whitespaces of the input.

Comment: No it doesn’t. The loop stops at the first character not fulfilling the condition. As every loop stops when the condition is not fulfilled.

Comment: @Holger right. Sorry, my bad.